# Redirect root directory excluding subdirectories using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two websites, domain1.com and domain2.com.  The admin section of both website is under the /admin directory.

I need the public website on domain1.com to redirect to domain2.com, but I still need to access the admin subdirectory on admin1.com.

Is this something I can easily do with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in the document root of `domain1.com` add this somewhere appropriate:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Many Thanks, that works for me.  I'll need to do some further jiggery pokery, as the files in the admin dir access files in the root and this seems to cause a redirect (would that make sense?).  But the redirect works itself if I just point at a blank html file